# What are Delphi 7 and Delphi 2009 differences which deals with characters, strings, unicode and the like?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, delphi-7

I had a class that only worked in Delphi 7 and after several attempts of converting it into Delphi 2009 we finally agreed to change our project into Delphi 7.

The project more or less done, but I want to give the 2009 thing another shot.

**Aside from Sizeof(Char) equals 1 in Delphi 7 and 2 in Delphi 2009, what are other changes that I need to be aware of?**

Additional:
It might help to know what I'm converting into 2009, so [HERE](http://blog.naver.com/rozio?Redirect=Log&logNo=100004822664) it is.
It's the `unit HanInput;` part. It translates keys (in english) and outputs the Korean characters. The way he uses the indexes is really confusing, each Korean character HAD a size of 2 so a lot of that code must be changed.

Sadly, I don't understand Korean, so it's pretty hard for me to guess the some semblance of an algorithm.

Comment: A google translate of that page from Korean to English (copy paste the text via http://translate.google.com - the interactive translate inside Google Chrome does not work) gives English that is OK to read.

Comment: Tried that, still didn't make any sense. (well, some parts made sense, but those parts didn't help much).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dian you can check this paper [`Delphi and Unicode`](http://www.embarcadero.com.pl/tech/tech-notes/codegear/delphi-and-unicode-marco-cantu.pdf) from Marco Cantù, wich explain in a great way the Unicode string support in Delphi.